# How to delay a submit event until another event is completed in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making a chrome extension that creates and pops up an overlay once a specific button is clicked. Clicking the button on the current page takes it to another one. I'd like to pop an overlay once the button is clicked, and only take it to the next page once the overlay is closed. This is my first project using JS so I'm a bit lost.

This is how I create the overlay

```
//injecting css
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL("css/overlay.css");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.head.appendChild(link);

//setting button's ID for easy referencing
var button = document.getElementsByName("proceedToCheckout")[0].setAttribute("id", "proceedToCheckout");

var overlay = document.createElement("DIV");
overlay.setAttribute("id", "overlay");
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

var url = chrome.extension.getURL("terry.jpg");
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.setAttribute("id", "terryImage");
img.setAttribute("src", url);
overlay.appendChild(img);
```

and this is how I go about the main click function

```
document.getElementById("proceedToCheckout").addEventListener("click", function()
 {
     alert("Do you really need that?");
     document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
     event.preventDefault();

     //disable overlay once clicked
     document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("click", function (){
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    })

})
```

Since I'm using event.preventDefault(), it does not let me continue the event. Is there any other way I can go about this? Thanks.